# wagtail cms content deploy to production

Tags: django, deployment, content-management-system, wagtail

I am study on the popular django cms framework - wagtail and coming to question: how do you deploy your developed contents - like pages/documents/images to production environments?

I am puzzled because these contents(like page) are saved into database, essentially they are just database tables rows but not a resource in git repo, so if I develope a simple web site in my dev and when I come to deploy to prod, it's not as simple as a git push. what is the best practice on this?

I read some codes from torchbox, there are some database dump and records pulling tasks using fabaric, not sure if that's the preferred way and neither can fully understand them.

Or if it's production site, is it supposed that everyone add content there and prod is the source of truth, there won't need of "content deployment" as all but only those schema changes via souths migration or other static resources only.

Please help if anyone has got experience on this and provide guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On our (Torchbox) sites, all content entry usually happens on the production site, so we don't need to push any database content as part of our regular deployments. Many of our sites have tens or even hundreds of editors, so it would be almost impossible to synchronise the content across multiple installations of the site.

Whenever we need to transfer content from one installation to another (for example, deploying the production site for the first time, or pulling a snapshot of the live site to help with development), we use the Postgresql `pg_dump` command to make a SQL dump of the complete database, then restore it at the destination using the `psql` command. Tools like Fabric can be used to automate this, but this isn't essential.